# Pandas: Adding conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a set of columns, on which I want to perform a conditional operation as follows:

```
foo = 0 * foobar2['var1']
foo.loc[foobar2['var1'] > 0] += foobar2.loc[foobar2['var1'] > 0, 'var1']
foo.loc[foobar2['var2'] > 0] += foobar2.loc[foobar2['var2'] > 0, 'var2']
foo.loc[foobar2['var3'] > 0] -= foobar2.loc[foobar2['var3'] > 0, 'var3']
foo.loc[foobar2['var4'] > 0] -= foobar2.loc[foobar2['var4'] > 0, 'var4']
```

That is, I want to sum `var1`, `var2`, and subtract `var3`, `var4` - whenever these variables are positive, as negative variables indicate missing values and similar in my data set. This code works, but is quite slow. Is there some more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Did you try using case statement?

Comment: Python has no such statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is the fastest I have tried:

```
foo = foobar2.clip_lower(0)
foo = foo['var1']+foo['var2']-foo['var3']-foo['var4']
```

This approach is a tiny bit little slower:

```
foo = foobar2.clip_lower(0)
foo['var3']*=-1
foo['var4']*=-1
foo = foo.sum(axis=1)
```

You can also use the `apply` method for a one-liner, which is simpler and clearer but also slower even than your approach:

```
foo = foobar2.clip_lower(0).apply(lambda x: x['var1']+x['var2']-x['var3']-x['var4'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Excellent idea. Sometimes copying is faster than selecting.